# Placing a decimal point just before last two digit of a number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query as below

```
|| LPAD (TRIM (TO_CHAR (RWTEXPT_STD_AMOUNT, 'FM9999999999999D00')), 15, '0')
```

its giving the result : `000011545467.00`

what i need is : `000000115454.67`

i have tried `'FM9999999999999D00'` and `'999999999999D99'` but it gives the same results `000011545467.00`

what i need is `000000115454.67`

Comment: This is not as formatting issue. Oracle doesn't provide any scaling capability in formatting because you may do it by yourself with trivial mathematical operations: division and multiplication

Comment: What is your input data?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your string value to a number, divide it by 100 and then format it:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_NUMBER(RWTEXPT_STD_AMOUNT)/100,
         'FM000000000000D00'
       ) AS result
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (RWTEXPT_STD_AMOUNT) AS
SELECT '000000011545467' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 000000115454.67 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/urZUyzPp)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it this way

```sql
Select To_Char(14.5, 'FM000000000000D00') "NMBR" From Dual
--
--  NMBR           
--  ----------------
--  000000000014.50
```

Put any number of leading zeros within the format. Zero means zero and 9 is a placeholder if there is a number present. Letter D is for decimal point character. You can use G for grouping character too.
Regarding decimals - if your column has integer value like 1467 and you know that last two numbers are decimal numbers then just put 1467/100

```sql
Select To_Char(1467/100, 'FM000000000000D00') "NMBR" From Dual
--
--  NMBR           
--  ----------------
--  000000000014.67
```

Regards...

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt match the required result , it gives 000011545467.00 while the needed is 000000115454.67

Comment: @Moe There is an addition... It looks like you need division.... Could you provide content and the type of your column?

Comment: thanks for your collaboration content is '000000011545467' type of column ( VARCHAR2)

Comment: Then to_number(column_name) /100.put this expression as number to be formated.